# Is there a disadvantage in using a global function instead of a private static method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, methods, static

I tend to be annoyed to have to write `this.myMethod()` or `ClassName.myMethod()` instead of just `myMethod()`.
Especially when the method is a stateless utility function, that doesn't need to access the fields directly.

Here an example:

```
function method1() { }

class App {
    main() {
        method1(); // I want to use this
        App.method2();
    }

    private static method2() { 
        // stateless and don't need access to fields
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is any reason to not use a global function instead of a private static method (or vice-versa).

Comment: you mean `window.method()` instead of `this.method()` or `App.method()`?

Comment: No, just `method()`, like in the example I provided

Comment: Is the same ;). I'll describe it more in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many reasons to not use global methods.

First is typing. Methods types are already connected to class/instance. To type global function you have to also overwrite `global` module.

Second is name collisions. You can easily overwrite one global method by another. I case of class's methods: you can name every private method in classes `method` and none will be overwritten.

Third is you can't use `this` as class instance in global function.

Fourth is speed (but I don't know how much) private method is in basic scope, and global one is in last one. So V8 in runTime will check each of scope between this and global.